# How to find an odd prime factor of $F(2013)$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Here,

$F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1,$ and $F(n) = F(n − 1) + F(n − 2)$ for $n ≥ 2.$

Please give hints, not full answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the divisors of $2013$. But first try with a smaller number.

Comment: @DanielFischer Here, we have $gcd(2^{11}-1,F(2013))=89$, but what can we do in general ?

Comment: $F(n)$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number.

Comment: @Peter What do you know about $F(n)$ and $F(kn)$?

Comment: OK, I see it. $F(n)|F(kn)$ , right ? So, we simply take a proper divisor $d$ of $n$ and calculate the prime factors of $F(d)$ , which  are also prime factors of $F(n)$.

Comment: @Peter how are you getting $F(n) | F(kn)$ ?

Comment: @Saikat I do not know how to prove it, I only noticed that it solves the problem.

Comment: @Saikat One way is induction. Another way is to use Binet's formula and the corresponding formula for the Lucas numbers.

Comment: For instance, $$ 89 \mid F_{11} \mid F_{2013}. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. The $(kn)^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number is a multiple of $F(n)$, where $k, n \in \Bbb{N}$.
2. $2013 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 61$